# keeping interval reference for clear interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

im a little stumped on this one. Basically I have a piece of code where when you click a div it fires off the code below, which makes another div blink green to red until the button is clicked again. The problem is when the function is called again the reference to animation var is gone and the div keeps blinking.

```js
function muteEvent(id) {
  var button = "#muteBox".concat(id.charAt(id.length - 1));
  var value = $(button).css("background-color");
  var slider = "#sliderKnob".concat(id.charAt(id.length - 1));
  var animation = function() {
    if ($(slider).css("background-color") == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
      $(slider).css("background-color", "red")
    } else {
      $(slider).css("background-color", "green")
    }
  }
  if (value == 'rgb(128, 128, 128)') {
    $(button).css("background-color", "red");
    var timer = setInterval(animation, 1500)
  } else {
    alert("here");
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(button).css("background-color", "#808080");
  }
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` returns an ID you can use with `clearInterval`: `var timer = setInterval(animation, 1500); ... clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: I am doing that, reference to that id is lost when i call the function again.

Comment: Not according to the code you've posted. You never store the value of `setInterval` in the first place, and you call `clearInterval` with a function argument, not an interval reference.

Comment: It is the same logic, i edited the code with your solution. Still same problem, interval isn't stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearInterval` takes an identifier (returned from `setInterval`) in order to stop the recurring timer.  Save this identifier somewhere that will still be in scope by the time you call `clearInterval` - noting that it will be a separate call to `muteEvent` the way your code is set up.

```js
var intervalId = null;

function muteEvent(id) {
  var button = "#muteBox".concat(id.charAt(id.length - 1));
  var value = $(button).css("background-color");
  var slider = "#sliderKnob".concat(id.charAt(id.length - 1));
  var animation = function() {
    if ($(slider).css("background-color") == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
      $(slider).css("background-color", "red")
    } else {
      $(slider).css("background-color", "green")
    }
  }
  if (value == 'rgb(128, 128, 128)') {
    $(button).css("background-color", "red");
    intervalId = setInterval(animation, 1500)
  } else {
    alert("here");
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    $(button).css("background-color", "#808080");
  }
}

$("#muteBox2").click(muteEvent.bind(null, "2"));
```

```css
#muteBox2 {
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="muteBox2">Mute</div>
<div id="sliderKnob2">Slider</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried putting the var intervalId inside the function scope and that s why it didn't work. It needs to be put in the global scope outside the functions.